# add class on div from href page after clicked on button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add some class on div  from href page with `window.location.href('link');`

and this javascript function is excecute after button is clicked

this is my full code

```
$(".crtresto").click(function(){

        window.location.href = ('useron?on=profil&to=12345');

        //This class is in the files useron
        $('#crtresto').addClass('active');
        });
```

so, the conclusion
if i click the button with class (.crtresto) then the page will be directed
to *useron?on=profil&to=12345*, after directed  to that page 
then automatically add class from the id(#crtresto)

thank you before

Comment: So what is the question? Try to clearly state what you want to do, what you've tried, what doesn't work and in what way it doesn't work. We shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: so, the conclusion if i click the button with class (.crtresto) then the page will be directed to useron?on=profil&to=12345, after directed to that page then automatically add class from the id(#crtresto)

Comment: That's a fact, not a question. And it's false, it won't work.

Comment: hemt.... ,,, my question is how to add the class from id(#crtresto) on useron file after
i click the button

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. After redirecting you cannot perform any action. So better option is you write the code to add class on useron page.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#crtresto').addClass('active');
    });
```